# Animating table rows reording with d3.js

Tags: animation, d3.js

I want to reorder table's data and animate the table's row exchange smoothly.

Code can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/HCLe5/1/

```
var table = d3.select("body").select("table#d3table");
var tHead = table.append("thead");
tHead.append("tr");
tHead.selectAll("th").data(thead).enter().append("th").text(function(d) {return d.id});
var tBody = table.append("tbody");
var tr = tBody.selectAll("tr").data(tbody).enter().append("tr");
tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d){return d.row})
    .enter()
        .append("td")
        .text(function(d){return d.value + d.id})

// Some magick row position manipulation
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure an animation that involves rows moving around is going to be hard to do with an actual `table` element - row order is defined by insertion order, so there's no positional info for d3 to interpolate.